# Combining two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following 2 queries which work as expected:

```
declare @user varchar(3)
declare @phrase varchar(255)

set @user = 'xyz'
set @phrase = '%nav%'

select ug.*, wap.*, w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_access_permissions wap on ug.id = wap.allowed
inner join widgets w on wap.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase

select w.widget_id, ug.*, wdp.*, w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_deny_permissions wdp on ug.id = wdp.denied
inner join widgets w on wdp.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
```

The first query shows records for any widgets which @user has access to based on the @phrase provided.  The second query shows records for any widgets which @user does not have access to based on the @phrase provided.

How can I combine these 2 queries into 1 so if someone has access based on a group, but because he is in another group which is declined in the deny table, he does not get to see the results?

I don't know if my last sentence makes sense...

EDIT: Added table names, table columns and a little sample data:

```
user_groups

table
id
display_value
employee_code
dept
persnl_typ_code

sample row 1
1000
group 1
xyz
i.t.
gen

sample row 2
1008
group 2
xyz
i.t.
gen

==========

widget_access_permissions

table
id
widget_id
allowed

sample row
0
0
1000

==========

widget_deny_permissons

table
id
widget_id
denied

sample row
0
0
1008

==========

widgets

table
widget_id
widget_name
widget_description
widget_header
widget_sub_header
widget_content

sample row
0
widget name goes here
widget description goes here
widget header goes here
widget sub header goes here
widget content goes here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005, you can use [`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) :

```
select w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_access_permissions wap on ug.id = wap.allowed
inner join widgets w on wap.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
EXCEPT
select w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_deny_permissions wdp on ug.id = wdp.denied
inner join widgets w on wdp.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
```

This takes the results of the first (allow) query, and **subtracts** the results of the second (deny) query, leaving you with just those widgets that the the user is allowed and NOT denied.

Note I have altered your original `SELECT` lists, as `EXCEPT` requires the two queries to have (effectively) the same `SELECT` list, and it seems to me that what you are interested in is the widgets.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way would be to use a sub query:

```
declare @user varchar(3)
declare @phrase varchar(255)

set @user = 'xyz'
set @phrase = '%nav%'

select ug.*, wap.*, w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_access_permissions wap on ug.id = wap.allowed
inner join widgets w on wap.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
and w.WidgetId not in (

select w.widget_id
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_deny_permissions wdp on ug.id = wdp.denied
inner join widgets w on wdp.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
)
```

Not sure how the performance would be for this though.

EDIT:

I think you may be able to remove the need of a sub query by using the following:

```
declare @user varchar(3)
declare @phrase varchar(255)

set @user = 'xyz'
set @phrase = '%nav%'

select ug.*, wap.*, w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_access_permissions wap on ug.id = wap.allowed
inner join widgets w on wap.widget_id = w.widget_id

Left Join widget_deny_permissions wdp on ug.id = wdp.denied
                        and w.widget_id = wdp.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
and wdp.Id Is Null
```

This would depend on your schema and data

Comment: The first query works, but the second one does not.  Seems like my schema is not compatible.

Comment: @oshirowanen - If you'd like to use the 2nd query then add in an example of your schema and data (if you can) to your question and I will try to amend it to work correctly.

Comment: I've added everything you wanted.  I think.

Comment: I think, Barry's second solution should work. Maybe I would use `and wdp.id is null` instead of `and wdp.Widget_Id Is Null`, it seems safer that way though may be inessential here.

Comment: @Andriy - I agree with you. After seeing the table structure it is probably better to use the ID from the table rather than the widget_id. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: @Barry, it still does not work for me.  Returns too many results.

Comment: @oshirowanen - I have created some sample data and it works fine for me. There must be some other scenarios within your data.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly , you want to union the permissions(most restrictive approach) whereby if a user is permitted in one group and denied in another , he should get that widget, if this is the case, You can do like this ,

```
declare @user varchar(3)
declare @phrase varchar(255)

set @user = 'xyz'
set @phrase = '%nav%'

select ug.*, wap.*, w.*
from user_groups ug
inner join widget_access_permissions wap on ug.id = wap.allowed
inner join widgets w on wap.widget_id = w.widget_id
where ug.employee_code = @user
and w.widget_name like @phrase
and w.widget_id NOT IN (
       select w.widget_id 
         from user_groups ug
         inner join widget_deny_permissions wdp on ug.id = wdp.denied
         inner join widgets w on wdp.widget_id = w.widget_id
         where ug.employee_code = @user
         and w.widget_name like @phrase
        )
```

Comment: He should not get the widget if he is in 1 group which is allowed access and in another group which is denied access.  He should only get the widget if he is in a group which is allowed access and not part of any group which is denied access.

Comment: However, your script works, so you probably missed out the "not" in your sentence above which says "he should get the widget"?